# How to remove vector x from (x'Ax)/(x'Bx)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are there any simple expression for the following scalar?

$$a=(x'Ax)(x'Bx)^{-1}$$

where $x'=$transpose of $x$, $A,B\in\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ and $x\in\mathcal M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb R)$. In fact I'd like to find a way to eliminate $x$. If $n=1$ then we will have $AB^{-1}$, but what about $n>1$?

Best
Alireza

Comment: @idm At least as written now, you are incorrect: $x^T A x$ is a scalar and $x^T B x$ is also a scalar.

Comment: What do you meanr by eliminate $x$? If you call $C=x' Ax$ and $D=x'Bx$ then you have elimated $x$, because $a=C/D$.

Comment: @Ian: You're write, it was from the first version. I erased my post. Sorry to not have make it before.

Comment: You can rearrange your equality to $x'(A-aB)x=0$. So unless $A=aB$, this equation will always depend explicitly on the choice of $x$.

Comment: Thanks Semiclassical, That's very helpful. Alireza

Answer (score 0):

In higher dimensions you cannot eliminate $x$. For a concrete example, look at $M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ and consider

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \\
B = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now consider your quotient for $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $x=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. In the first case you will get $1/3$; in the second case you will get $1/2$.

In one dimension (that is, considering $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over itself), every matrix is a scalar multiple of the identity, and so this doesn't occur. Here's the algebra. If $A=aI$ and $B=bI$:

$$(x^T A x)(x^T B x)^{-1} = (x^T a I x)(x^T b I x)^{-1} = ab^{-1} (x^T x)(x^T x)^{-1} = ab^{-1}.$$

Incidentally, in the case $B=I$, this is a very important situation for eigenvalue problems: in this case your function is called the Rayleigh quotient, which is a powerful tool for computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors of symmetric matrices.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Your explanation is very helpful.